# nicescroll not working with mulitple of classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

My nicescroll jquery script worked fine with one div, but when i added 2 divs it stopped working. I don't understand why. I have used || to separate them but it doesn't work. I don't understand where i am going wrong.

**JQuery**

```
  $(document).ready(
  function() {
  $(".video-wrapper" || ".news-wrapper").niceScroll();
  }
  );
```

Comment: i tried that but it didnt work. It places the the ".new-wrapper" scroll is now next to the ".video-wrapper" scroll

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".video-wrapper" || ".news-wrapper").niceScroll();
```

The above statement means nothing in jQuery , you need to do the following if you want to call `niceScroll()` no two div's

```
$(".video-wrapper").niceScroll();
$(".news-wrapper").niceScroll();
```

Comment: the same thing happens. basiclly i have the video-wrapper on the left of the page and the news wrapper on the right of the page. The scroll for the video wrapper stays inside the div but the scroll for the news wrapper is outside the div and on the left of the page right next to the video wrapper.

Comment: EDIT i fixed it i had to update nicescroll to a newer version